# Hierarchy in multisite

Tags: multisite, hierarchical

I'm looking into building a multi site (sort of like blog portal) but with a hierarchy. So there's a mother organization (with own content) with different "chapters" (say 10, each with own content) and then each chapter have "bloggers".

So on a blog it should read "Part of chapter X" and a list of other bloggers in the same chapter.

So I need a way to group the bloggers and put them in a hierarchy.

I'm not sure about the URL structure but some bloggers will have own top domains but most will have subdomains (WordPress MU Domain Mapping will help with this).

I'm looking for some thoughts about how this could be solved, as well as tips on plugins.

I found Network Sites Hierarchy: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpmswpmu-network-sites-hierarchy/ which looks promising but has very little activity. Also WP Multi Network http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-multi-network/ seems to be of help.

Any help before I jump into the "install and test a bunch of plugins"-phase is highly appreciated.

Thanks!
Dennis

Comment: This article, [about **not using** MS](http://halfelf.org/2011/dont-use-wordpress-multisite/), may give you some ideas for *using MS* and categorizing stuff.